# How to connect redux store to a function (react-native)?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux, expo

How to connect redux store to a function to get the store state and also to dispatch some actions?

I tried the following code but getting an 'undefined' error.

```
function App() {
    const handleBarCodeScanned = async ({type,data}) => {
        console.log(this.props.card_details);
        this.props.adj_card_details(data);
    };

    return ( <View />);
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        card_details: state.carddetails.cardDetails,
    }
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return {
        adj_card_details: (new_card_data) => dispatch({type: 'ADJ_CARD_DETAILS',payload:new_card_data}),

    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App);
```

Comment: I would recommend using redux hooks, very easy to set up and use: https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks

Comment: Thanks a lot,that worked!

Answer (score 0):

The state in redux has to be accessed like this:

```
const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    displayData: state.content.displayData,
  };
};
```

Always using **state.content** in front of what you want to retrieve. In your case I assume it would be the following code:

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        card_details: state.content.carddetails.cardDetails,
    }
}
```

Hope it helps